# PHP convert text time to Time format

Tags: php, sql, date

it is possible to convert express time in 1h22m14s or 22m55s
To the format 01:22:14, 00:22:55 in an easy way using php?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, create a format string, the use the `DateTime` class to parse from the format using the method `createFromFormat`.   It's really a magical class!

PHP.net has excellent documentation on this: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

They even have an example close to your specific question you'd just need to tweak it a bit:

```
  $mytime = '23h15m03s';
  echo DateTime::createFromFormat('H\hi\ms\s',$mytime)->format('H:i:s');
```

If you have a part the drops off occasionally (like hours in your example) you'll need to play with the format to get it to work.

Comment: @webDev looks like it will work for that case, but how would you handle the example: `22m55s`.  You'd need some additional logic (`strtotime()` would see it as `hh:mm` and you'd get 22:55:00 not 00:22:55)

Comment: You are right @Ray, I did not think about that, simple tweak i have done, would you please see and let me know whether that will work or not, thank you very mush

Comment: Sure it will work, though I'd never recommend it!  IF you're going the regular expression route, you could probably figure a single expression to cover both cases.

Comment: now i can understand why you dont recommend, yeah that will not good in every situation. there might be 22h or 56s only too. you can delete my solution. I understood and thank you

Comment: @webDev  ok, I'll comment it out.  You should take a swing at creating the regex--it would be a good learning experience.  If you find it, add it as an answer!